# Append script dynamically that inserts an Object tag with flash embedded

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I need show ads at page load. So, I append the scrip tag to the head (this script includes a `<object>` tag with flash inside). The problem is that the ad is never shown until the user clicked the page.

```
<head>
    <script id="ad" async type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        (function (d) {
            var script = d.getElementById('ad');
            script.src = 'http://syndication.exoclick.com/splash.php?idzone=2089279&type=3';
        }(document));        
    </script>
</body>
```

After append the `src` this is shown:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="E_cHVyZVBVNHVf" name="E_cHVyZVBVNHVf" data="//syndication.exoclick.com/pu.swf" style="position:fixed;visibility: hidden;left:0;top:0;width: 0px;height: 0px;z-index:999999;overflow:hidden;">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="menu" value="false">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="FlashVars" value="fs=1">
</object>
```

I've tried to create an script and append it to head but the doesn't work. ¿Any idea?

I've also tried making `document.documentElement.click()`, and `document.body.click()` or `focus()` but doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what about this?

```
window.onload = function(){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src="//adurl";
  script.async = true;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```